# Switching from MySQL_query to PDO causes unwanted escaping

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have recently been switching all of my old mysql_query calls to PDO's. I've encountered an issue that wasn't present in the mysql_query configuration. When I try to input a variable into a database with quotations, It appears as escapes in my database. I have disables magic quotes in my php.ini file.

```
$myString = "Enter 'one' now";
$sql=$pdo->prepare("UPDATE $tbl_name SET string=:myString WHERE etc...);
$sql->execute(array(':myString' => $myString));
```

This updates to

```
Enter \'one\' now
```

What I need is

```
Enter 'one' now
```

This wasn't happening before I switched to PDO. Is there a way around this without losing security?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean it returns this ... You are doing an update it shouldn't return that string ...

Comment: Sorry, it updates into the database those values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) enabled on your server, the [PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php) for it tells you various ways you can turn it off.

In regards to your comment: You can also try creating a `php.ini` file in your home directory with the following:

```
magic_quotes_gpc = off
magic_quotes_runtime = off
magic_quotes_sybase = off
```

If that doesn't work, then contact your host to address the issue.

Comment: Ive tried adding php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off and php_value magic_quotes_gpc off into my .htaccess. I get an error 500 on my site when I add those lines.

Comment: Are you using shared hosting? If so, who is it as they may have a different way to turn it off (such as using a php.ini file in your home directory, see my edit)

Comment: Just to clarify, the php.ini will only need those three lines? It wont mess with anything else php wise?

Comment: It all depends on your web host @Milksnake12. Each server is configured differently but a lot of web hosts will allow you to place a php.ini file in your `home` folder so you can override trivial configuration items such as this. Don't take my word for it though, contact your provider or sys admin.

Comment: I added a files with those lines and it worked. Thank you very much!